# How to save in local storage of Safari Private Mode

Tags: cookies, safari, local-storage, incognito-mode

I have an app that saves a user name in local storage. 
It works fine with every browser except `Safari` in `private mode`.

Is there a way to save this variable in Safari private mode? I tried using cookies but it's also doesn't work...

Any work around?

Comment: Did you find a way to deal with this? I've tried using amplify.js which wraps multiple storage technologies. But after a window.location the memory is cleared again.

Comment: @pidm , I answered the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I implemented a LocalStorageHandler that checks if the browser supports local storage, if it doesn't support then I use a Cookie.

This is the function that checks if it supports local storage:

```
localStoreSupport: function ()
{
    var testKey = 'test', storage = window.sessionStorage;
    try
    {
        storage.setItem(testKey, '1');
        storage.removeItem(testKey);
        return true;
    }
    catch (error)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And this is how I dealt with false:

```
if (this.localStoreSupport())
    {
        localStorage.setItem(name, value);
    }
    else
    {
        document.cookie = name + "=" + encodeURIComponent(value) + expires + "; path=/";
    }
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Hello Offir, I suggested an edit with changing testKey from `test` to `__localStoreTest__` which got a few approves before you rejected it. 

I believe that they key used here ('test') is too normal to use in such a check, it might very well create a nightmare for someone who just copied code from here and later started using localStorage with 'test' key somewhere else.

Could you, please, explain why you rejected it?

Answer (score 5):

From Safari 11 onwards they support localStorage in private mode, the same as other browsers
Commit: https://github.com/WebKit/WebKit/commit/91d15f887ff7174f7754b25b8dc8ab459951e5e1
Discussion: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=157010